# Is the usage of nonetheless in the below sentence correct?

Tags: word-usage

I have written the below sentence.

> Panicked that his presence had been exposed, by his own folly
> nonetheless, Diego immediately jumped in the cover of the tree.

The sentence here is supposed to mean that of all the things that could have gone wrong, it was his own mistake that caused his presence to be discovered. His own folly, of all the things.

The sentence sounds good to me but I still want to confirm if the usage is correct. Feel free to correct the sentence.

Comment: It's not a the below sentence. It's just *this sentence*. What's a below?

Answer (score -1):

The usage of "nonetheless" does not sound right to me in that sentence since the word is usually used to denote something happening despite a previously mentioned condition, and the latter is not made clear in your sentence.

A more stylistically interesting alternative for your sentence would be:

> Panicked that his presence had been exposed, by - out of all things - his own folly, Diego immediately jumped in the cover of the tree.

Comment: I would prefer - of all things - (no 'out').

Comment: One could just directly replace *nonetheless" with *of all things*: "...exposed, by his own folly of all things, ..."